# Rails. How to update a bunch of entries inside a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a situation where users can apply to a job (called Job Application). When the employer of the job accepts/approves the user for the job, the model should automatically check if the user have another job within the same time.

1) If there is, it will raise an error message saying the user already have a job. Which is done by the self.errors.add

2) Should set the status of all other application around that time for the user to "User Already Booked".

I was able to do 1) without any problems, however when I do 2) the SQL transaction keep giving me "rollback". I first got all the entries I want to update, then I tried using update_all method to update them. However the database won't commit the transaction and keep giving me a rollback.

The following is my code. Can anyone tell me how to save records(not just 'self' but other entries) in a model. Or at least how to debug that rollback message.

```
#Inside my Job Application Model
#Run the custom validation I made
validate :does_user_have_job

private

#check if User have another job_application that overlaps with the current one
def does_user_have_job
  #pre define variables for easier understanding
  job = self.job
  id = job.id
  start_time = job.start_time
  end_time = job.end_time

  #This part is a query to the database to find whether there is overlap.
  #Please ignore this as this is not important.
  overlaps = self.user.job_applications.joins(:job).where.not(job_id: id).where(approved: true).where("(jobs.start_time >= ? AND jobs.start_time <= ?) OR (jobs.end_time <= ? AND jobs.end_time >= ?)", start_time, end_time, end_time, start_time)

  #if there are overlaps, then set the status of those overlaps to "User Already Booked"
  if not overlaps.empty?
    #Find the entries that I want to set status to
    #I am picking out these entries for testing purposes
    #Do not ask my why I am using application where approved = false 
    job_applications = self.user.job_applications.where(approved: false)

    #This is the first method I used but the transaction
    #got rollback therefore I used the second method
    #job_applications.update_all(status: "User Already Booked")

    #This is the second method I used but the transaction
    #still got rollback and error message was empty
    job_applications.each do |job_application|
      job_application.assign_attributes(status: "User Already Booked")
      job_application.save(validate: false)
      puts job_application.errors.messages
    end  #scroll down for more vvvvvv

    #Third method I tried as suggested by "steve klein"
    #Still got rollback
    job_applications.each do |job_application|
      job_application.update_attribute(:status, "User Already Booked")
    end

    #After setting the status of other entries I raise an error
    self.errors.add(:job_application, "User is already booked")
  end
end
```

Error message I got upon inspecting

```
SQL (0.1ms)  UPDATE "job_applications" SET "status" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "job_applications"."id" = ?  [["status", "Already Have Job"], ["updated_at", "2015-06-24 14:06:18.480217"], ["id", 72]]
<<< inspecting error
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007f9f3dc94378 @base=#<JobApplication id: 72, job_id: 70, user_id: 1, master_id: 1, status: "Already Have Job", user_reviewed: false, master_reviewed: false, started_user: false, ended_user: false, created_at: "2015-06-23 17:14:52", updated_at: "2015-06-24 14:06:18", approved: false>, @messages={}>
(1.0ms)  rollback transaction
```

Comment: Change `job_application.assign_attributes(status: "User Already Booked")` to `job_application.update_attribute(:status, "User Already Booked")` and remove the call to `save`.

Comment: tried it just now. still got rollback. Am I not suppose to rewrite other entries in the model?

Comment: What errors do you get?  Maybe you can't set status to that value for some reason.  You can also try testing it out in the Rails console if you are unsure of syntax etc.  I just did that now and confirmed this should work, assuming you are not getting a validation error.

Comment: i just tried inspecting the error. As you can see at the bottom of the post, it set the status to what I want, but it got rollback with no error messages

Comment: I've set up a [chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81430/steve-and-harunojikan) to discuss.

Comment: You appear to have a typo in my method.  Should be `update_attribute`.

Comment: Does the `update_all` work if you trigger it from the console?

Comment: Great point @fylooi... the issue turned out to be a manual call to `self.errors.add` in the method which caused rollback.  Code is working now with `update_attribute` but could probably modify to call `update_all` on the collection.

Comment: Doing so much in the validation is a very very bad idea. Should create a separate class to orchestrate this behaviour.

Comment: @fylooi thanks for the advise. Do you have any good resources to what you said? creating a separate class? I just started coding 4 months ago and I am pretty new to rails. It would be great if you have any resources you can share.

Comment: @fylooi I just look at validators. Is that what you meant? Something like the example in this website? http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validator.html

Comment: It's on a more general level than that. Try to understand what the usage of each class / method is, and use it for that purpose. For instance, validators should only check whether the record is valid and return true/false. If you want to do extra work after the validator returns false, have another method in a different class which checks whether the object is valid, and do that work.

Comment: @fylooi I see. So in my case, I already raised an error when the user already have a job in a specific time slot, but at which point and where should I set the status of user's other applications that falls within the time slot to "Canceled due to double booking"? Should I do that in another class? If so then how should I do it? Or should I do it in the controller? The reason I need this is because User can apply to a lot of jobs in the same time slot until one employer approves the user for that job. Sorry if I am stupid, but please bare with my stupidity.

Comment: Take a look at http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/, particularly the section on Service Objects. You might refactor out job approval into a `JobApprovalService` class.